# Toast will not show before try/catch Thread.sleep()

Tags: android, sleep, toast

I've got a curious problem when I try to `show();` my Toasts. You'll see below two Toasts separated by a `try/catch and Thread.sleep();` In this case the second Toast, `toast2`, will show up but `toast1` will not.

If I remove the `try/catch` both Toasts will show up with no problem.

I've seen elsewhere on SO that `toast.show();` makes a request on the UI Thread which can be conflicted by other operations. I'm wondering if that is the same problem I have here with the `Thread.sleep();` How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

`TestService.java`

```
    ///Debug - Show a Toast
    // Toast does NOT show up
    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(context,"Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast1.show();

    //Try to sleep for roughly 2 seconds
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Debug - Shows a Toast
    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(context,"Sleep completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast2.show();
```

Comment: Is this running on the UI thread?

Comment: what r u tring to do??u want ur UI thread to wait for 2 seconds?or u want your control flow to wait for 2 seconds what is ur need??

Comment: Go learn UI basics first

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In real life, you will probably have some logic instead of just "sleep", right?
THe right android way of, per your example, starting a service would be through executing it on a worker thread. This will make sure you won't get an ANR.

your could would look something like:

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(context, "Sleep completed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast2.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(context, "Service Started",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast1.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Try to sleep for roughly 2 seconds
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

    }.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you suspend ui thread right after first toast it does not
 have chance to be shown. And by the time sleep is over, the time for first
toast has passed.

That sounds like most plausible explanation but I may be wrong. Need to dig really deep in Android
code to find out for sure.

Comment: I believe you are right. I reduced the time down to nearly nothing and `toast1` popped up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need to create a Toast that lasts more than 2sec (why you should use `Thread.Sleep(2000)` before sending another Toast?).
So I've just found [this link](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/19/indefinite-toast-hack/) that provides a very good example.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, I will attempt to resolve by using AsyncTask as suggested, but my use-case is the following:

1) I want to display a Toast message (begin broadcast message)
2) If the condition is right, I broadcast message1 to clients.
3) I sleep 2 secs to allow broadcasting to complete.
4) I broadcast message2 to clients all the time.
5) If it's done I would Toast another message (broadcasting messages completed)

I've come up with the following workaround example (though the sequence the toast messages were still shown in reverse):

```
package com.toasttester;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PreSleepToast pst = new PreSleepToast();
        pst.execute();
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);//to allow broadcasting to complete
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        callToast1();
    }
    private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
     };

    public class PreSleepToast extends AsyncTask<Void, byte[], Void> {
        /**
         * The sender socket on which we send connections.
         */
        public PreSleepToast() {
        }

        /**
         * Polling loop for outgoing connections.
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            handler.post(r);
            return null;
        };
    };

    public void callToast1(){
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm my solution only works on marshmallow didn't work on nougat....in nougat it replaces the "Message2" it seems....whereas in marshmallow it shows after it.

Comment: now i'm puzzled at nougat's behavior.....even if i use an ArrayList to queue up my Message1 and Message2 one before the sleep and one after.....and then i start the asynctask that post a runnable that eventually loops through the messages in the ArrayList to Toast them......but still only the last message is shown......